# Sort DateGridTemplateColumn MultiBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In a view in my application I have the following definition for a `DataGridTemplateColumn`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date and Time" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="ModuleInfos.FileCreationDateTime">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="16" Height="16" ToolTip="Original date changed!"
                       Source="pack://application:,,,/UI.Resources;component/Graphics/InformationImage.png">
                    <Image.Visibility>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{converters:MultiDateTimeConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="ModuleInfos.FileCreationDateTime" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                            <Binding Path="PartListInfos.ModuleDateTime" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Image.Visibility>
                </Image>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource DataGridTextBlockStyle}">
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{converters:MultiDateTimeConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="ModuleInfos.FileCreationDateTime" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                            <Binding Path="PartListInfos.ModuleDateTime" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The MultiDateTimeConverter is:

```
internal class MultiDateTimeConverter : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
{
    private static MultiDateTimeConverter converter;
    private const string dateFormatString = "dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm:ss";

    public MultiDateTimeConverter()
    {

    }

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values != null && values.Length == 2 && values[0] is DateTime)
        {
            if (values[1] is DateTime)
            {
                if(targetType == typeof(string))
                    return ((DateTime) values[1]).ToString(dateFormatString);
                if (targetType == typeof (Visibility))
                    return Visibility.Visible;
            }

            if(targetType == typeof(string))
                return ((DateTime)values[0]).ToString(dateFormatString);
            if (targetType == typeof (Visibility))
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        return values;
    }


    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return converter ?? (converter = new MultiDateTimeConverter());
    }
}
```

My problem is the `SortMemberPath` of the `DataGridTemplateColumn`. In the past the content of the column was just bound to the property `ModuleInfos.FileCreationDateTime`. But now the content depends on the two properties `ModuleInfos.FileCreationDateTime` and `PartListInfos.ModuleDateTime`.

What do I have to do to enable the sorting to the correct values?

Answer (score 0):

Add sort-descriptions for as many properties as you want to DataGrid's ItemsSource. Below code sorts by two properties if you click on FileName column header. Use e.Handled = true to stop default sorting behavior.

Conceptually do this :

```
private void Dgrd_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
        {            
            DataGridColumn col = e.Column;
            if (col.Header.ToString() == "FileName")
            {
                CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Dgrd.ItemsSource);
                view.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("FileName", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
                view.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("CreatedBy", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
                view.Refresh();

                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else
                e.Handled = true;
        }
```